# Causal Mediation Analysis Sensitivity Analysis

Tags: r, multiple-regression, mediation, sensitivity-analysis

As part of a research project we have to perform causal mediation analysis(CMA) on R. Since `mediation package` is kind of limited for our research purposes, we decided to use `medflex`, but medflex currently does not have build-in sensitivity analysis functionality. I looked up online and there is not much literature on sensitivity analysis in CMA either.
Are there any papers or any leads on how to perform sensitivity analysis for CMA?
My treatment variable and mediator variables are continuous variables while the outcome is binary. Thank you!

Comment: VanderWeele (2010, DOI: 10.1097/EDE.0b013e3181df191c) discusses sensitivity analysis that does not rely on the framework of Imai et al. That said, what is it about `mediation` that is not sufficient for your analysis? My understanding is that the only real difference is that `mediation` can only estimate risk differences, but that is usually an acceptable estimand. `mediation` is a more mature package than `medflex` and having the sensitivity analysis built is a major plus.

Comment: We needed to use `bayesglm()` instead of regular `glm()` because some coefficients and their standard errors were close to 0 and z score would blow up. `mediation` does not allow for `bayesglm()` so we went with `medflex`.